# Read variables from another form that's changing

Tags: c#, variables

I have two forms, let's say form1 and form2.  Inside form1, I have variable v1.  Now in form2, I wish to display the value of v1, but the problem is, v1 will changing constantly.  I have passed v1 into form2 when I initialize form2 inside form1 as follows:

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
   public int v1;

   public form1()
   {
       form2 f2 = new form2(v1);
   }
}
```

then inside form2

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
   public int v2;

   public form2(int v1)
   {
       v2 = v1;
   }
}
```

This should work fine, but if I have say 20 variables, it would be passing a large amount of arguments into the constructor.  Of course, I could put all the variables inside an array of list of some sort first, but just wondering if there's other better ways of accomplishing this task, without using static (since I've heard using static is pretty bad).

Comment: Instead of variables you may consider using __Properties__, which have a setter in which you can do stuff like updating other spots in your program. Of course you still need to have references to these spots in place but then there is only __one place responsible__ for the updating, not everyone that changes the values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always pass the form1 as parameter to the form2

```
form2 f2 = new form2(this);
```

and then

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
   private form1 _form1;

   public form2(form1 form1)
   {
       _form1 = form1;
   }

   private void SomethingElse(){
     var res = 10 - _form1.v1;
   }

}
```

Comment: by using this method, is there a way to retrieve the variable v1 from form2 without making it public inside form1?  or do I need to use encapsulation?

Comment: @AndyWei  Public/Protected/Internal... it will depend on your own decision  (and namespaces).... instead of thinking why make it public? ask why not? will you provide the DLL as an API to someone else and you are afraid of bad use of variable v1??? Sometimes code gets uglier when we over complicate things....  just make it public and that´s all....  it will work and it's done.
First finish your project, make it work and in the end if you have time, you can always refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class with all necessary parameters:

```
public class SharedData
{
   public SomeValue1 { get; set; }
   public SomeValue2 { get; set; }
   public SomeValue3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SharedData _data;
    public Form1()
    {
        _data = new SharedData();
        var form2 = new Form2(_data);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private SharedData _data;
    public Form2(SharedDatadata data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
}
```